# glmnet ununderstandable: Error in lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

I have installed R and Rstudio just to use glmnet for a multinomial
logistic regression. I keep getting the following error:

```r
Error in lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha,
nobs, : one multinomial or binomial class has 1 or 0 observations; not allowed
```

whenever I plug in the dependent variable observations of my data. That comprises 120 "numeric" entries: 1 through 4. The predictors are 6=4 continuous+ 2 categorical.

I created a table "data" with 6 columns in which I changed the class of the categorical observations to "factor"

```r
data <- cbind(x1,x1fat)  # x1=4 columns, x1fat=2 factor columns
```

Then I set

```r
x <- model.matrix(~.+0, data=data)  # 120x12 matrix
```

to create the matrix of regressors observations with one-hot-encoded factor data. To feed the dependent variable y
observations in glmnet, I use the following line

```r
y <- model.matrix(~.+0, data=y1)  # y1 is the 1-column table of imported observations
```

Now, the command

```r
fit <- glmnet(x, y, family = "multinomial")
```

prompts the aforementioned error.

I do not comprehend why the following do not prompt any errors:

1. If I randomly generate the y vector through
   `y=sample(1:4,120,replace=true)`
2. If I include the intercept column in y:
   `y <- model.matrix(~., data=y1)`

I am completely stuck here. Any comment is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the count of examples in each category level? Error sounds like you don't have sufficient examples.

Comment: Thanks for the input. They are  91    20     8     1. Very unbalanced. Why would glmnet not even return any model in unbalanced cases, instead of providing one albeit with very poor predicting performance?

Comment: It's not about the imbalance, but rather that the level with only 1 sample is degenerate. I don't know the internals for `glmnet`, but generally one should always have more samples than coefficients being estimated, which is violated when estimating a coefficient for only one sample. Either obtain more samples or discard that level.